# jquery datepicker minDate not working in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
$("#s_shipDate_from").datepicker({
        dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd",
        showButtonPanel: false,
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/Cal.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            if($('#s_shipDate_to').val()!="")
            {
                var fromDate = new Date(dateText);
                var toDate = new Date($('#s_shipDate_to').val());
                $('#s_shipDate_to').datepicker("option", 'minDate', fromDate);

                if(toDate<fromDate)
                {
                    alert("'TO' date must be more than 'FROM' date.");
                    $('#s_shipDate_to').datepicker("setDate", fromDate);
                }
            }
        }
    })
    $("#s_shipDate_to").datepicker({
        dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd",
        showButtonPanel: false,
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/Cal.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        beforeShow : function (input, inst) {
            if($('#s_shipDate_from').val()!="")
            {
                var fromDate = new Date($('#s_shipDate_from').val());
                $('#s_shipDate_to').datepicker("option", 'minDate', fromDate);
            }
        },
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            if($('#s_shipDate_from').val()!="")
            {
                var fromDate = new Date($('#s_shipDate_from').val());
                var toDate = new Date(dateText);

                if(toDate<fromDate)
                {
                    alert("'TO' date must be more than 'FROM' date.");
                    $('#s_shipDate_to').datepicker("setDate", fromDate);
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

I have `From` and `To` datefields, using jquery-ui datepicker. I wrote the above code so that, `To` date can't be more than `From` date, and it works great in FF/chrome, but doesn't work in IE(8). Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

check your

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

tags if it contains space after "text/javascript "  IE will not run the script

Comment: IE runs the script because calendar shows up and I can click on the dates to select them, it's just that the minDate doesn't seem to work